# Normalisation or scaling of a column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to scale a particular column in pyspark. In this case i want to do scaling in results column.My data frame looks like -

```
id      age       results
1        28         98
2        27         12
3        28         99
4        28         5
5        27         54
```

I have done so far -

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
     [(1,28,98),(2,27,12),(3,28,99),(4,28,5),(5,27,54)],
     ("id","age","results"))

minmax_result = df.groupBy("id").agg(min("results").alias("min_results"),max("results").alias("max_results))

final_df = minmax_result.join(df,["id"]).select(
((col("results") - col("min_results")) / col("min_results"))).alias("scaled_results"))

final_df.show()
```

it gives me like -

```
id      age       results    scaled_results
1        28         98          null
2        27         12          null
3        28         99          null
4        28         5           null
5        27         54          null
```

Comment: Do you want to scale it across all ids, or for each id separately (groupby)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use StandardScaler function in Pyspark Mllib something like this :

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="features", outputCol="scaledFeatures",
                                withStd=True, withMean=False)
scalerModel = scaler.fit(new_df)
scaledData = scalerModel.transform(new_df)
```

Refer : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html

Upvote if works

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're planning to scale the column across all ids, so you won't be needing the `groupby` operation, unless you're going the UDF route. I'd suggest going with the following:

```
min = df.agg({"results": "min"}).collect()[0][0]
max = df.agg({"results": "max"}).collect()[0][0]

df_scaled = df_test.withColumn('scaled_results', (col('results') - min)/max)
```

I presume you're dividing each cell by the min value instead of the max value by mistake, but that might the use case as well.